# MD5 function returns empty result

Tags: mysql, md5

I am trying to return an MD5 encoded string of a value from my database, but it just returns a blank result (not null, just blank).
I have tried just running this query and get the same result:

```
SELECT MD5('test');
```

I have tried restarting the MySQL server, MySQL Workbench, etc. But get the same result.
If I try running the same command on a different database/server, it returns the hash string just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a setting I disabled on accident?

Comment: Did you tried to run the query over CLI (mysql.exe) ?

Comment: No, I ran it in mySQL workbench.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prior to MySQL v5.5.3, `MD5()` returned a binary string.

By default, MySQL Workbench does not display binary strings (to avoid accidental misinterpretation); however it is possible to display binary string values in output grids: View > Edit > Preferences > SQL Editor > Treat `BINARY/VARBINARY` as nonbinary character string.

Alternatively, either upgrade your MySQL server or transcode the result to a non-binary character set:

```
SELECT CONVERT(MD5('test') USING utf8)
```

Comment: Thanks that corrected it!Weird that it showed the result when using the same Workbench but different databases/servers.

Comment: Ah, I thought it might be due to the IDE. Good explanation!